# MS excell =IF formula across multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to create an `IF` formula across `E1`, `F1`, `G1` and `H1`.

If true, it should display “Commence Fire Drill,” that is situated on the data sheet `C5 (E3:H3=Data!A1)` and if False “All in Order” that is situated on the data sheet `C6` in `G1`.

I tried

```
=IF(E3:H3=Data!A1,Data!C5,Data!A6)
```

But it gives me an error: `#VALUE!`

How do I apply `IF` formula across `E` to `G`?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help to you:

put multiple cell conditions in AND Function,

```
=AND(A2="Bananas", B2>=30, B2>C2)
```

then put AND Function in If Function,

```
=IF(AND(A2="Bananas", B2>C2), "Good", "Bad")
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer posted by @Anonymously,  first create `AND()` condition  to check whether the value in cell `Data!A1` is same as in the cells of `Sheet1!E1:Sheet1!H1`. If the value is true you will get "Commence fire drill" and if not then "All in Order"

@Patrick try this formula `=IF(AND(E1=Data!A1,F1=Data!A1,G1=Data!A1,H1=Data!A1),Data!C5,Data!C6)`